# Formatting MVC 5 Razor link as a string

Tags: javascript, mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

MVC 5 doesn't seem to like JavaScript that much.
I am creating link in JavaScript to a success method in my Ajax call.

Razor:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Amount", "Action", "Controller", new { id1 = "a", id2 ="b"}, new { target = "_blank"})
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#element').html('<a href="' + '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id1= "a", id2= "__id2__" })'.replace("__id2__", id2) + '" target="_blank">' + data[1] + '</a>');
```

This link works, but, I am not sure it's the best solution. Tried with a `onclick` method on the element instead, and with a separate method for handling the link, but still doesn't really get around this replacing.

And if it has more parameters should I just be chaining them?

```
.replace("__id2__", id2).replace("__id3__", id3).replace("__id4__", id4) etc
```

Comment: While  we have the tag system to avoid the usage of tags in the title, your code interacts with that language, so that's okay (*just for Razor*), please remember for future that (*like in this case with JavaScript*), the tag shouldn't be put in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really comment on your structure in Razor, as I am unfamiliar with that framework, however, your replacing structure could be improved.

By using a function, alongside a dictionary, you can simplify this greatly.

```
function massReplace(str, dict){
    for (var i in dict){
        str = str.replace(i, dict[i]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Whilst also converting the `"__id3__", id3` structure into:

```
var dict = {
    "__id2__": id2,
    "__id3__": id3, 
    "__id4__": id4
};
```

And then simply:

```
$('#element').html('<a href="' + massReplace('@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id1= "a", id2= "__id2__" })', dict) + '" target="_blank">' + data[1] + '</a>');
```